# Using request-promise to make an API call using jwt. [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE] received

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

I'm learning nodejs and trying to make an API call. The API uses JWT to authenticate.

I created these functions to sign a token:

```
function token() {
  const payload = {
    iat: Math.floor(new Date() / 1000),
    exp: Math.floor(new Date() / 1000) + 30,
    sub: "api_key_jwt",
    iss: "external",
    jti: crypto.randomBytes(6).toString("hex")
  };
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    jwt.sign(payload, privatekey, { algorithm: "RS256" }, function(
      err,
      token2
    ) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(token2);
    });
  });
}

exports.genToken = async function() {
  const header = {
    "x-api-key": api
  };
  const data = {
    kid: api,
    jwt_token: await token()
  };

  async function authorization(req, res) {
    try {
      const auth = await rp({
        url: authurl,
        method: "POST",
        headers: header,
        body: data
      });
      res.send(auth.body);
    } catch (error) {
      res.send(404).send();
    }
  }

  return {
    "x-api-key": api,
    Authorization: "Bearer " + authorization()
  };
};
```

This works fine. Then I created a function to make the API call:

```
const token = require("./index").genToken;
const rp = require("request-promise");

exports.getOrderBook = function(res, error) {
  const full_url = url + "order_book";
  const auth = token();

  rp({
    url: full_url,
    method: "GET",
    headers: auth,
    body: {
      market: "btceur"
    },
    json: true
  })
    .then(function(response) {
      res(response);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      error(err);
    });
};
```

And I call it using `Express`:

```
routes.get("/orderbook", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const book = await orders.getOrderBook();
    res.send(book);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

However, when I call my API, it shows an error in console:

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of
>   type string or Buffer. Received type object.

I guess the error is something with the token generation, because if I `console.log(auth)` in the `getOrderBook` function, it shows `Promise { <pending> }`, so probably an object is being passed as the jwt token.

Is it really the problem? I tried a lot of different solutions that I found on internet, however the concept of `Async/Await` is new to me, and I'm having some troubles to figure it out.

Thanks a lot in advance guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `getToken` is an `anync` function, the return is wrapped in a `Promise` as well so you would need another `anync/await`:

```
exports.getOrderBook = async function() {
  let response;
  try {
    const full_url = url + "order_book";
    const auth = await token();

    response = await rp({
      url: full_url,
      method: "GET",
      headers: auth,
      body: {
        market: "btceur"
      },
      json: true
    });
  } catch (e) {
    // handle error
    throw e
    // or console.error(e)
  }
  return response;
};
```

In this line as well `Authorization: "Bearer " + authorization()`, `authorization` is returning a promise

```
const bearer = await authorization()

return {
  "x-api-key": api,
  Authorization: "Bearer " + bearer
};
```

For error handling wrap entire thing in `try..catch` block

```
exports.genToken = async function() {
  try {
    const header = {
      "x-api-key": api
    };
    const data = {
      kid: api,
      jwt_token: await token()
    };

    async function authorization(req, res) {
      let auth;
      try {
        auth = await rp({
          url: authurl,
          method: "POST",
          headers: header,
          body: data
        });
        // res object not available
        // res.send(auth.body);
      } catch (error) {
        // res object not available, better throw error and handle in your middleware
        // res.send(404).send();
      }
      return auth
    }

    const bearer = await authorization()
    } catch (e) {
      // handle error
    }
  return {
    "x-api-key": api,
    Authorization: "Bearer " + bearer
  };
}
```

Comment: I tried this before asking the question, however I still get the same error

Comment: can you paste the stack trace

Comment: I've made some modifications to the code. Now I'm not getting that error anymore, however my `auth` token is nested inside a JSON. When I try to console.log the auth, I get this: 
{ 'x-api-key': 'xxxxxxxxx',
  Authorization: 'Bearer [object Object]' }

So I guess the problem is how I'm handling the response from the genToken function

Comment: you should extract out in that case

Comment: auth["token"] resolved the problem! Thanks again for your help. Since I extracted and adjusted the code based on your answer, I'll mark it as the solution. Thanks!